# how to send firebase notification with sound, icon, color, tag all field using new firebase update http v1 in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

how to send Firebase notification with sound, icon,  tag all field using new Firebase update HTTP V 1  in REST ? before i send this field with notification data

```
$notificationData = [
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $description,
    'click_action' => 'HomeActivity',
    'icon' => 'ic_notification',
    'color' => '#CD201F',
    'tag' => 'general',
    'sound' => 'sound.mp3',
    'notification_type' => 'order_status',
    'android_channel_id' => 'order_status',
];
```

like this now how to send this all field?